# Java:Read Tokens

Tags: java, token

The code should Read the file and Check it .If Datatype or Keywords or Operation . The code compile with no erros but the jTextArea don't appear The result of check . May be I forgot something but jTextArea don't read anything .

```
  public boolean IsKeyWords(String x)
{
    List myList = new ArrayList(); 
String[] keywords= new String[] { "for" , "if" , "else" , "return" ,"and" , "goto" , "true" ,"false" , "break" , "continue" , "do" , "this" , "class" , "delete" , "void" , "public" , "private" , "operator" , "static" , "struct" , "volatile" , "while" ,};
Collections.addAll(myList, keywords);
    for(int i = 0;i<myList.size();++i)
    {if(x.equals(myList.get(i)))
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}       
 public boolean IsOperaions(String x)
{
  List myList1 = new ArrayList(); 
String[] Operations = new String[]{"+", "-" , "*" , "%" , "/" , "=" , ">>=" , "<<=" , "&=" , "+=" , "-=" , "/=" , "*=" , "^=" , "++" , "--" , "==" , "!=" , ">" , "<" , ">=" , "<=" , "!" , "&&" , "||" , "|=" , ">>" , "<<" , "&" , "~" , "^" , "|"};
Collections.addAll(myList1, Operations);
    for(int i = 0;i<myList1.size();++i)
    {if(x.equals(myList1.get(i)))
        return true;

    }
    return false;

}

public boolean IsDatatype(String x)
{
  List myList2 = new ArrayList(); 
  String[] Datatype = new String[]{"int" , "char" ,"float" , "double" , "String"};
  Collections.addAll(myList2, Datatype);
    for(int i = 0;i<myList2.size();++i)
    {if(x.equals(myList2.get(i)))
        return true;

    }
    return false;

}
```

Here the button that when I press on should Read the File and check it.

```
private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   File f =chooser.getSelectedFile();
   String filename2=f.getAbsolutePath();
   BufferedReader br;
   try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename2));
    String line;
    ArrayList <String> tokens=new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer words;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    words = new StringTokenizer(line);

    while(words.hasMoreTokens())
       {
       for(int i=0;i<line.length();++i)
       {
       tokens.add(line.getBytes().toString());

       }
    words.nextToken();

       }
      for(int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++)
    {
      jTextArea1.setText(tokens.get(i).toString());

   if(IsKeyWords(tokens.get(i)))
  {
   jTextArea1.setText(tokens.get(i).toString());
   }
   else if(IsOperaions(tokens.get(i)))
  {
   jTextArea1.setText(tokens.get(i).toString());


   }}
    br.close();

    }
    }
       catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }     

    }
```

Comment: `if(x==myList.get(i))` That's not how we compare Strings in Java. This question has been asked twice today :_(

Comment: but when I use that I get error

Comment: still I have same problem don't read anything :(

Comment: I edited it but I have the same problem .. may be in funtion of reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the `String#equals` `String` comparison issue which has been well flagged, the main issue is that `BufferedReader` `br` is being closed within the read loop which throws an `IOException` when attempting to call `BufferedReader#readLine`. Move the `close` statement to a `finally` block

```
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, adding a byte array to the token `List` will result in an unreadable work in the `JTextArea`. Replace

```
tokens.add(line.getBytes().toString());
```

with

```
tokens.add(line);
```

Collections in Java use *generics* to avoid casting. Apply them to all instances of `List`, e.g.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: It gave me something in The TextArea now but it's werid not the same in file              "  [B@752719ad  "

Comment: Why are you adding a byte array to the token `List`? Just add the `line` `String`

Comment: yessssssssss it worked !!! :)

Comment: I wish can vote for you but still nub

Comment: KK thank you I did :)